# How to zip (compress) a JS array

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression

How would I compress an array?

I am trying to compress an array. I have tried using the lz-string library and converting to/from strings, but I get `null`/`0`/`[]` on decompress.

This is what I'm doing:

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    array[array.length] = i % 255;
}
var string = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
var compressed = LZString.compress(string);
var decompressed = LZString.decompress(compressed);
var dearray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < decompressed.length; i++) {
    dearray[i] = decompressed.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZV5Za/18/

Comment: May I ask why you need to compress the array? (I'm assuming the example is just sample data)

Comment: @Cerbrus because I am experimenting with compression algorithms, and yes the data is sample data as loading data over ajax makes the example heavy.

Comment: By the way, it looks like the compression's working just fine. It's the translation from string to array that's not working.

Comment: @Cerbrus yea I was thinking that was the case, maybe an encoding issue (i.e. UTF8?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it does work, I just had a typo.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZV5Za/20/

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    array[array.length] = i % 255;
}
var string = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
var compressed = LZString.compress(string);
var decompressed = LZString.decompress(compressed);
var dearray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < decompressed.length; i++) {
    dearray[i] = decompressed.charCodeAt(i);
}
console.log(array.length, array);
console.log(string.length, string);
console.log(compressed.length, compressed);
console.log(decompressed.length, decompressed);
console.log(dearray.length, dearray);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the way you're forming the array into a string, and back.

Why not use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) / [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) **([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV5Za/19/))**:

```
var string = array.join('|');
var dearray = decompressed.split('|');
```

Or maybe even better: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) / [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) **([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV5Za/19/))**
(This actually preserves data types):

```
var string = JSON.stringify(array);
var dearray = JSON.parse(decompressed);
```

I don't know how you'd fix the "string -> array" step you are using, though.

Comment: Would that not inflate the data though?

Comment: A bit, but you can compress the JSON string. The advantage is that this preserves data types such as integers, floats, booleans, instead of just returning a load of strings. Your string <-> array conversion will only work when the array's filled with integers. (Well, should, but I can't see why it won't fill the `dearray`)

Comment: I'm actually dealing with an array of bytes (technically a `Uint8Array`), but converting to standard arrays for convenience/simplicity.